# JPA: Inheritance.TABLE_PER_CLASS set parent table name

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I use `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS`. Somehow I can define the name of the child table, but not of the parent table.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(name="foo")
public class Parent {
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="bar")
public class Child extends Parent {
    ...
}
```

Results in:

```
 Schema |  Name  |  Typ   
--------+----------------
 public | parent | Table  
 public | bar    | Table
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, the problem was in front of the keyboard... me.

Solution for anyone having the same issue and don't want to waste as much time:

In the strategy `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` there is **NO** parent table. All attributes of the parent class are directly stored in the child tables. So, if there is no parent table, it can not be renamed!

But why was it listed in my database? Before choosing `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` I tried differed strategies like `InheritanceType.JOINED` which in deed creates a parent table. Using the property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` for development, I assumed the database will always match my java implementation (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689769/8345434). However, `create` only drops data and **not** tables which are no longer part of the implementation. Thus, after each application restart I so the old table which was no langer part of the application.

```
 Schema |  Name  |  Typ  |  Creation Date  
--------+--------+-------+-----------------
 public | parent | Table | a long time ago 
 public | bar    | Table | now
```

Answer (score 0):

**you didn't do anything wrong!**

when you are using the `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` you cannot directly specify the name of the table for the Parent entity. The name of the parent table is typically derived from the name of the parent entity class.